# Make a value to be selected in the dropdown selectbox with a jQuery cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery. I have set value in cookie and I wanted a dropdown value selected. Here is my HTML code:

```
 <select id="usrole" class="form-control usrole txtboxdesign" >
                    <option>Select Role</option>
                </select>
```

Here is my code that populate dropdownvalue using jQuery axios:

```
function GetAllRole() {
alert('Role Value');
axios.get(all_RoleList + '/GetAll', authToken).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    let select = document.getElementById('usrole');
    for (let i = 0; i < result.data.resultSet.length; i++) {

        var optname = result.data.resultSet[i].roleName;
        var optid = result.data.resultSet[i].id;
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = optname;
        el.value = optid;
        select.appendChild(el);

    }
});
}
```

I have console the cookie value and I got the value. But I cannot set selected the dropdown value. Here is my code

```
var roleid = $.cookie("roleid");
$('#usrole option[value="' + roleid + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

This code is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use `.val()`

```
var roleid = $.cookie("roleid");
$('#usrole').val(roleid);
```

That will do the job i think

Example

```js
var dropdowns = [
    {'Id': 1, 'value': 'Blackberry'},
    {'Id': 2, 'value': 'Nokia'},
    {'Id': 3, 'value': 'Xiomi'}
];

function GetAllRole() {
    let select = document.getElementById('usrole');
    for (let i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {

        var optname = dropdowns[i].value;
        var optid = dropdowns[i].Id;
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = optname;
        el.value = optid;
        select.appendChild(el);
    }
}

GetAllRole();
var roleid = 3;
$('#usrole').val(roleid);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="usrole" class="form-control usrole txtboxdesign" >
                    <option>Select Role</option>
                </select>
```

Comment: I have tried this but this did not work . I have checked first i populate data then I have to select and I have done by this way still didnot work

Comment: Well do one check then, which process is executing first. Is your selection value statement is executing before your dropdown generated

Comment: No my selection value statement is executing after . don't know what is the wrong

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example, take a look

Answer (score 0):

If your changed value is not reflected on the UI, Please try:

```
var roleid = $.cookie("roleid");
$('#usrole').val(roleid).change();
```